# Why I can curl my page on internet but can't reach with browsers? Nginx

Tags: nginx, firefox, deployment, uwsgi, linode

I try to deploy hello world with flask on the internet at linode.
I use docker with two containers: one nginx, another flask+uwsgi.
nginx server block and other settings are default.
**pyroblast.dev.conf**

```
upstream app_master {
    server  1.1.1.3:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pyroblast.dev;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass app_master;
    }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**uwsgi.ini** is basic too:

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:app
master = true
processes = 2
socket = :8080
```

I can reach my site with curl:

```sh
curl pyroblast.dev
```

It return the the simpliset html which i have.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world from Flask</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But i can't reach it with browsers.
Mozilla redirects to 443 port even if I explicitly demand pyroblast.dev:80
I can't open site on my phone with chrome and mozilla too.
I tried disable browser.fixup.fallback-to-https in about:config of firefox - didnt help
I check SiteSecurityServiceState.txt of mozzilla - my site is not present here.
What else can be problem?

Comment: See https://get.dev/ - the .dev tld is supposed to be https only. Browsers respect this, so redirect automatically, but your curl obviously doesn’t

Comment: jesus...what a trap. i was sure i was doing something obviously wrong: nginx, hosting settings, mozilla.... thank you. apparently you are right.